# Likelihood ratio test: multiple observations

Tags: likelihood, likelihood-ratio

I have 32 samples and I can go through and calculate the likelihood of my observed data under different models and do a LRT for a given point under multiple models.

However, is there a way that I can incorporate information from each of the samples in assessing the total model fit?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a sample consisting of 32 observations? Or 32 samples consisting of $n_i$ observations each for $i$ between 1 and 32?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to parse that question.. I fit a binomial model for data from 32 individuals. I know how to do a LRT on each individual separately, but not as a group